# How to dynamically add multiple values to a single key in HashMap?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I want to add multiple card values to a distinct single key in HashMap at run time
if i give an input like this

```
s 2 
d 5 
s 3 
d 7 
s 4
```

it should give an output like

```
s 2 3 4 
d 5 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For this you need to use `ArrayList` as values and `String` as keys in `HashMap`. Here is an example:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
myMap.put("s", list);
```

If there are `n` key, then to dynamically add values to each key, you can do following:

```
//1. Get the value (list here) for the key you want to add new values. 

ArrayList<Integer> myList =  myMap.get("s");

//2. Check if myList is null
if(myList==null){
    myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

//3. Now add the values to this list.


myList.add(5);
```

Comment: but if there is n number of keys then how do i dynamically add values to the respective keys

Comment: This is wrong. If the list for key `s` is not present in the map, you have to put it, otherwise the elements added to the list (`5` in this case) will be lost.

Comment: Yes you are right, but this is general idea I've presented here. It's not the working code with validations. See the first word 'Hint'.

Comment: @Kaushal28 well, the hint is wrong, then, because it points to an error

Answer (score 0):

if you don't wanna get your hands dirty and instead rely on bulletproof 3rd party library classes check the following classes, that should do the work:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html